# How do I get unittest run in pycharm when import something from __init__.py

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I'm trying to run tests in my project in pycharm with the following structure:

```
root/
  tests/
    __init__.py
    mytest.py
```

When I import my_settings from **init**.py into mytest.py, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 116, in <module> modules = [loadSource(a[0])]
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 40, in loadSource module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "/Users/user/temp/test/tests/mytest.py", line 2, in <module> from tests import my_settings
  ImportError: cannot import name my_settings
```

I can run test fine with the following command:

```
python -m unittest discover -s tests/
```

Here is a sample project: https://github.com/xcompass/pycharm-broken-test-path

I'm running pycharm 3.4.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Try deleting the pycharm test configuration and running the tests again.

Comment: @Dunes Thanks. I tried, the same. Here is what I did:
1. Clone the repo

2. New Project in PyCharm and Import the source

3. Navigate to mytest.py and Right click on "Run 'Unittests in mytest'"

Then I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is far too late for the original poster, but I had exactly the same problem with PyCharm and thought putting my solution might help those that stumble across this via search.

One possible explanation for this problem, is that Python is not importing from the path you expect. Insert the following lines above the point where the ImportError occurs:

```
# using example module from above
import tests
print(tests.__file__)
```

Now re-run the tests in pycharm and examine the output.

What you may find, is that the path to the module "tests" is not what you expect. If that is the case, removing the errant module should fix it for you.

If that doesn't help, check the python path is what you expect by inserting the following lines above the error instead:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Also remove any build directories in your path, so you don't accidentally import a bad egg.

Finally, remove any *.pyc files from the directory:

```
find -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

This last one probably won't impact the problem above but caused py.test to fail for me after rebuilding a clean vagrant box.